Error running 'app': Couldn't terminate previous instance of app error in Android Studio
While developing in Android Studio, after making a change in the code, I click "apply changes" and encounter this error.

After unplugging the device from USB, plugging it in again and deleting the application, it can be installed successfully. Does anyone know the solution to this?
I've tried it with Android Studio Giraffe

This happens due to abnormal gradle demon behaviour. You can use command gradlew --stop

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@BobSmith It might happen due to Gradle daemon, but for me it did not.

@SamuelLindblom you can manually uninstall your app, then install it again.

Does this answer your question? Android Studio : Couldn't terminate the existing process for xxx

It doesn't work unless I manually delete my app and reinstall it and unplug and plug in the USB

+and it still pops up at irrelevant times. Therefore I cannot understand the source of the problem.
